# How to change the tick of the checkbox to black being by default in white in react-native-expo

Tags: react-native, checkbox, expo

I am needing to change the tick color to black when it is TRUE. which by default is white. I am importing my checkbox from expo-checkbox, I do not know what I would be doing wrong or if there is any property to change the color of it

```
<CheckBox
     disabled={false}
     checkboxDefaultColor="transparent"
     value={rememberMe}
     onValueChange={()=>setRememberMe(!rememberMe)}
     color={rememberMe ? {"checkboxDefaultColor": "transparent", "color": "#000"} : undefined}
     style={styles.checkbox}
/>
```

[image]